# Can lexical need be used for epistemic meaning?

Tags: semi-modals

> [i] He needn’t have told her.   [epistemic or deontic]
>
> [ii] He might have killed her.   [epistemic or dynamic]
>
> In [i] the perfect is internal in the epistemic reading (“It isn’t necessarily the case that he told her”), external in the deontic (“He didn’t have to tell her”). Similarly with [ii]: "It might be that he killed her" (epistemic), "His killing her was a possible but unactualised consequence of what he did" (dynamic).
>
> (The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language, p204)

The latter meaning, need's deontic, is somewhat familiar to me. But I don’t find any source yet how the word, lexical need, makes the epistemic sense. Would you let me know about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's [i] in a context which requires an epistemic reading:

> 1A: Amy’s found out that Ken got the promotion. Joe must have told her about it.
>   1B: He needn’t have told her—she might have heard it from Nancy.

*Need to*, as CGEL says, may be paraphrased as *be necessarily true that*.

Here’s a contrasting example which requires a deontic reading:

> 2A: Amy asked Joe whether she got the promotion, and he had to tell her that Ken got it.
>   2B: Oh, damn. He needn’t have told her—he could have just said it was still up in the air.

*Need to* may be paraphrased as *be obliged to*.

Both of these *needs* are rather formal and old-fashioned. In present-day speech they would both probably be expressed with a *didn’t* construction, and the epistemic sense would avoid casting Joe as the Agent:

> 1B: It didn’t need to be Joe who told her ...
>   1B: She didn’t need to hear it from Joe ...
>
> 2B: He didn’t need to tell her ...

And at least in US speech, *need to* itself would be much less likely than *have to*, in both situations:

> 1B: It didn’t have to be Joe who told her ...
>   1B: She didn’t have to hear it from Joe ...
>
> 2B: He didn’t have to tell her ...

In any case, the line between epistemic and deontic *need to* is fuzzy. *Need to* is mostly used prospectively: you *need to* do something in order to accomplish something else, whether that something is effecting some purpose or drawing some logical conclusion.